# Disable right click zone for touchpad

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

Does anybody know if there is a way to disable the right click zone of a touchpad in windows 10?

I think it's pretty annoying and not very accurate. I prefer the behavior of a mac touchpad, which doesn't have a right click zone, instead you just use a two-finger-click.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: check the manufacturer.  they might make a utility for doing that.

Comment: do a search for utility to disable touchpad. [there are alternatives](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/touchfreeze-disables-laptop-touchpad-when-typing/)

Comment: thanks for the hint, but I don't want to disable my touchpad, I just want to disable it's right click zone

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are sufficiently annoyed to try this, and you didn't say specifically what touchpad you have.  This will work on some touchpads.

You can turn a PTP back into a "generic mouse" by going to Device Manager, finding the touchpad, and disabling it.  Just the "HID-compliant touch pad"  You might need to reboot and/or restart to get the touchpad to boot up just as a mouse.

It is possible you will get simpler behavior in this mode which doesn't include a right click zone.  You will also lose other PTP functions that you may like.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide here and downloaded X-Mouse Button Control, then remapped my right click to left click.

Guide: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/restrict-or-disable-mouse-right-click-at-desktop-and-explorer/

Freeware link: https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

If you're like me and don't have ClickPad(tm) drivers like some HP or Dell laptops do, this seems to be the next best option.

Edit: never mind, this disables right click globally and prevents the two finger tap too.