# Disable *part of* touchpad on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

Due to the somewhat questionable placement of the touchpad on my ASUS ZenBook device I'd like to disable a certain part of it. Is there a way to do it?

Please note that I am not looking for ways to disable my **entire** touchpad, just a part. Please also note that I do not want to apply any physical modification of the computer (like putting on a tape).

EDIT: I've just found [this part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchpad-tuning-guidelines#super-curtains) of the official Win documentation which explicitely says it is possible to define 'curtain' regions on a touchpad in the registry from where no input is accepted. This is exactly what I was looking for so once I figured and tried out the exact solution I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Possible dupe of [Disable right click zone for touchpad](https://superuser.com/q/1424215)

Comment: @DavidPostill It is not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Microsoft's own Windows documentation there is a very handy and easy-to-understand guide about tweaking the behavior of the touchpad using certain registry values. It is accessible here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/touchpad-tuning-guidelines

For me the solution was to introduce a so called **super curtain region** on the right of the touchpad which is **completely disabled**, in the sense that no input can be initiated from that region, regardless of keyboard activity or anything else. It will still function when the input swipe originates from the enabled region of the keypad, but that is desirable in my opinion.

Steps taken:

1. Open regedit via Win+R.
2. Navigate to 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad'.
3. Create a new DWORD called 'SuperCurtainRight' to which I set the decimal value of 5000 (it's much easier to set it decimally instead of hex, there's an option to tell the registry you're doing that), which puts a 'input-disabled' section of 5 cm-s from the rigth border of my touchpad. Analogous 'SuperCurtainLeft','SuperCurtainBottom' and 'SuperCurtainTop' DWORDS can be introduced as well.
4. Another, secondary issue was that my touchpad is set off to the right of the centerline of the keyboard but the OS was not told about this, and this affects how Windows treats the touchpad sensitivity when you're typing (introducing the supercurtain regions effectively overrides this afaik, but I was trying to make sure everything is set the way it should be). The way to do it was to create a DWORD called 'HorizontalOffset'. It's value is calculated by subtracting x from y (see image) in cms, then multipling that value by 1000 to arrive at the required Himetric dimension (it's nothing too complicated: 1 Himetric = 0.001 cm). Since this can be both negative (if your touchpad is set off to the left) and positive (if set off to the right), but you can only create positive valued DWORDS, you'll also need to tell the sign of the value to Windows. You do this by simultaneously also creating another DWORD called 'HorizontalOffsetIsNeg' and set it's value to 0 if your horizontal offset positive, 1 if it's negative.

[image]

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.