# How to disable specific zone on touchpad so that thumb resting on button area doesn't cause erratic behavior

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I have used laptops with separate manual/mechanical buttons for many years, but need to get a new laptop and they all have full touchpads without separate buttons now.  My thumb naturally sits on the bottom left portion of the touchpad to quickly press the left-click button as my index finger moves the cursor, but because this zone is part of the "touch" area of the pad, almost all laptops freak out and move the pointer when my thumb slightly moves, or don't let my index finger move the pointer anymore at all until I lift my thumb up.

Is there a way to disable a certain zone of the touchpad directly over the left-click area so that my thumb can comfortably rest on the pad only to push down and left-click?  Seems like this would be a very valuable utility or option in touchpad drivers, but I have yet to find one.

Side note - no, "just use a mouse" is not a good option when you're not at a table/desk with a laptop.

Comment: I swear to whatever deitic principle you like that I would commit multiple capital felonies to have a laptop with either a real mouse or a tracball on one side instead of a stinking touchpad below the space bar...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - haha, agree.  I do not know why they took away the buttons...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable \*part of\* touchpad on Win 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1721893/disable-part-of-touchpad-on-win-10)

Comment: @harrymc, interesting!  Thank you for pointing this out.  I will play around with this to see if the "supercurtain" region setting can prevent this.  ty!

Comment: You can also use a piece of *thick* adhesive tape, such as the loop side of hook-and-loop tape, with the added advantage of comfort and tactile feedback that the thumb is in a safe area. *Caution:* removal may be difficult.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - yes, I'm aware this could be done, but being a programmer myself, it's kind of a joke that there isn't an easy option in touchpad drivers/settings to disable specific parts.  Going to try harrymc's suggestion above.

Comment: Using thick tape along the whole bottom will result in the touchpad not knowing if you are clicking the left side or the right side, and then you won't be able to right-click. I don't know if using supercurtain has this problem or not.